# How to be unchecked in checkbox in clone().insertAfter jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to copy the whole rows ,but checkbox unchecked when clicking add button.(in my code, 
if I check FOC checkbox and when I click add,it copy rows with Foc check).

In asp.net,

```
<table id="tblitems" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="additemtb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>UOM</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Minimal Order Qty</th>
      <th>FOC</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:190px;"></td>
      <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_ItemCode" CssClass="classItemCode readonly" Columns="8" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <input type="text" id="txtunitprice" name="txtunitprice" class="classUnitPrice number readonly" style="width:50px;" />
         <input type="hidden" id="hidunitprice" name="hidunitprice" class="classUnitPrice2" />
         <asp:Label ID="lblCurrency" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency" />
         <input type="hidden" id="hidcurrencyid" name="hidcurrencyid" class="classCurrencyID" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" id="txtqty" name="txtqty" class="classQty number decimaltextbox" style="width:50px" onkeyup="calculateAmount(this);" onblur="minamt(this);calculateAmount(this);" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_UOM" CssClass="classUOM readonly" Columns="5" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_Amount" CssClass="classAmount number readonly" Columns="8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency2" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="text" id="txtminorderqty" name="txtminorderqty" class="minorderqty number readonly" style="width:60px;background:none;border:none;font-weight:bold;color:Red;" />
       </td>
       <td style="width:1px">
         <input type="checkbox" id="chkFOC" name="chkFOC" class="classFOC btnborder" onclick="calculateFOC(this);" />
         <input type="hidden" name="hidFOC" id="hidFOC" class="classFOC2" value="false" />
       </td>
       <td style="width:90px;">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="copy" onclick="copyRow(this);">Copy</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete" onclick="removeRow(this);">delete</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add" onclick="addRow(this)">add</a>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="darkgray">
          <span class="classOverBudget chinese" >Purchase Order Amount is over limited budget.</span>
        </td>
        <td class="darkgray" style="text-align:right; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap">Total Amount</td>
        <td class="darkgray" >
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" CssClass="classTotalAmount number readonly" Columns="8" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency3" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="darkgray">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

In Javascript,

```
function addRow(name, selected){
  $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find('.classFOC:checked').attr('checked', false); 
  $(name).parent().parent().clone().insertAfter($(name).parent().parent());

  //adding remove function to next siblings
  $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find(".delete").attr('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

  selected = $(name).parent().parent().find(".mcdropdown input:hidden").val();

  //list of textbox or inputs elements to be empties
  $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find("input").val('');
  $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find(".classCurrency").text('');
  $(name).parent().parent().next('tr').find(".classCurrency2").text('');

  $(".promotion-container").css("height", $("#left").innerHeight() - 42 + "px");


  FormActionControl();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you edit to make it more clear please.

Comment: Thank for your concern on my problems.sorry for unclear code.I show only some code,not fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you can't uncheck the checkbox in a new row that is cloned from an existing row with a checked checkbox. I think that is probably because the line of your code that tries to do that is *before* the line that actually creates the new row. So simply switching the order of the first to lines in your function may fix it, however the code in the function is, well, pretty horrible and can be cleaned up a *lot*.

As far as I can tell your `addRow()` function is attempting to find the parent TR element that the clicked Add button belongs to, clone that row, and then uncheck any checkboxes in the new row and also set other fields in the new row to blank.

Something like the following might work - this is basically a cleaned up version of your code, except that:

- the new row with the checkbox is created *before* trying to uncheck anything
- everywhere you had `$(name).parent().parent()` I'm using a new variable `$currentTR` - not only is this more efficient it is 500% more readable
- everywhere you had `$(name).parent().parent().next('tr')` you seem to be trying to access the newly added row, so why not keep a reference to that new row as soon as you create it? I've done so with the new variable `$newTR`.

So:

```
function addRow(name, selected){
  var $currentTR = $(name).parent().parent(),
      $newTR = $currentTR.clone();

  $newTR.insertAfter($currentTR);
  $newTR.find('.classFOC:checked').attr('checked', false); 

  //adding remove function to next siblings
  $newTR.find(".delete").attr('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

  selected = $currentTR.find(".mcdropdown input:hidden").val();

  //list of textbox or inputs elements to be emptied
  $newTR.find("input").val('');
  $newTR.find(".classCurrency, .classCurrency2").text('');

  $(".promotion-container").css("height", $("#left").innerHeight() - 42 + "px");

  FormActionControl();
}
```

By the way, using jQuery to set an inline `onclick` handler is not a good plan, but I think fixing that is outside the scope of what you seem to be asking.

Note also that your function has an argument called `selected` that is assigned a value in the function, but although that won't cause an error it also won't do anything useful because firstly JavaScript passes by value so that will not cause anything outside the function to change, and secondly you don't even pass that argument in when you call the function.